# "Service Dependencies" not available for project

Tags: visual-studio

When you go to add a "Connected Service" you are brought to a page that contains options for services to connect.  One of the boxes is "Service Dependencies" but for some reason, this box is unavailable for many of my projects, mainly .NETFramework projects (can not convert to .NetCore which strangely does show the box).

I'm dealing with "Console Applications" and maybe that has something to do with it, but seems unlikely as there is another engineer who has the option (they aren't sure why).

Trying to learn what are the conditions for when that box will and won't show.  Additionally the "Publish" option also isn't shown. Hoping someone has some insights.